# sqldatasource, SQL doesn't run correctly

Tags: asp.net, sql, parameters, sqldatasource

This is a strange problem that I've been working on for a while. I have a `sqldatasource` with `select` and `update` statements. However the statements don't work correctly with parameters.

For example if in the SQL select statement I had `WHERE dept_id = '@DEPTID'` and then had:

```
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="DEPTID" Type="string" DefaultValue="10122" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

It doesn't work but if I removed the UpdateParameters and put instead `WHERE dept_id = '10122'` it works perfectly.

And I know the parameter is being passed correctly because I put in a `OnSelect="OnSqlSelecting"` in the sqldatasource tag with this in the codebehind:

```
protected void OnSqlSelecting(Object source, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < e.Command.Parameters.Count; i++)
    {
        Response.Write(e.Command.Parameters[i].ParameterName.ToString() + "<br />");
        Response.Write(e.Command.Parameters[i].Value.ToString() + "<br />");
    }
}
```

And it gave me the correct DefaultValue for the correct parameter. I didn't provide all of my code, but what are some usual explanations or fixes for this type of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove those single quotes from the '@DEPTID'.

Try :

```
WHERE [dept_id] = @DEPTID
```

Comment: Wow that's what did it. Of course it's so simple, I've only been stuck for 2 days! Thanks!